# ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta side by side with Async CTP (Version 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-ctp

I first installed the Async CTP (Version 3) and then ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta. However, I can't use the async keyword.

Are there any compatibility issues?

*There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151216/can-async-ctp-version-3-work-alongside-asp-mvc-3) for ASP .NET MVC 3 (which has no answers at the time of this writing).*

Edit: The async/await keywords might be broken before I install any of those. (I am still investigating.)

Comment: I found the post below that fixed the async/await keywords after uninstalling ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta. I still investigate whether it was the Beat or those KB Updates that caused the issue. http://codesnack.com/blog/2012/02/16/visual-studio-async-ctp-version-3-installation-issues/

Comment: Uninstall Async CTP (Version 3) and ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta. Then install Visual Studio 11/Beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uninstalling the KB hotfixes mentioned at [this](http://codesnack.com/blog/2012/02/16/visual-studio-async-ctp-version-3-installation-issues/) blog spot everything is working normally.